# Jquery math addition

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying to add through a jquery event and I'm getting NaN. What am I missing?

```
   <input type="hidden" id="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="3" onchange="valueadd(this)"/>

   function valueadd(ok){
var value=parseFloat($(this).val())+1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code should be:

```
function valueadd(ok){
  // "this" inside here refers to the window
  var value=parseFloat(ok.value)+1;
}
```

The inline onchange is actually an anonymous function:

```
function() {
   //"this" inside here refers to the element
   valueadd(this);
}
```

So "this" is an argument that gets called "ok" in the valueadd scope.  As the others have stated, though, you probably want to use jquery's bind so "this" inside of valueadd will point to the element.

Comment: +1 for explanation about the inline event handler (though I suspect it may not be grasped as I don't know many people who realize it)

Answer (score 6):

`this` is a reserved word in JavaScript, so you can't use it in the function argument signature.

I'd probably change that code to...

```
$('#skillcount').change(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val()) + 1;
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/5De46/).

...and drop the inline event handler.

To check if `parseFloat()` returns `NaN`, use `isNaN()`.

Comment: I don't have the this in it I wrote that for simplicity not knowing it was a reserved word. however the addition is comming up NaN still.It needs to be in a function since other things happen after this.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it simply like so:

```
<input type="hidden" id="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="3" onchange="valueadd()"/>

function valueadd()
{
    var value=parseFloat(this.value)+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Assign your behavior with jQuery since you have it available and are using it anyway. Don't use inline event handlers
2. A function bound by jQuery is executed in scope of the element on which the event occurred. Which means `this` is the element.
3. `this` cannot be used as a param name or anything other than to access the object in scope.

Use:

```
<input type="hidden" id="skillcount" name="skillcount" value="3" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#skillcount' ).bind( 'change', function()
    {
        var value = parseFloat( $( this ).val() ) + 1;
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: FWIW, unless you manually trigger the change event for a hidden input, no such event ever occurs. Change requires `focus`, change of value, and `blur`. Hidden inputs can never gain or lose focus, so they never "`change`"